# Square cells in matplotlib table?

Tags: matplotlib, sudoku, matplotlib-table

I want to display a sudoku grid from the values in an array.

Here's my code

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
ax.table(cellText=sudoku2,loc="center")
plt.show()
```

And here's my output
[sudokugrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMD7L.png)

How do I get the cells to be squares ?
I'm lost.

Comment: try this:`ax.set_aspect('equal')`

Comment: hmm it's better, but still not square [link](https://i.imgur.com/GyygH3Z.png)
How does it work exactly ?

Comment: `ax.table(cellText=sudoku2, colWidths=[0.05]*9,loc="center")`Since the table parameters are only cell widths, I think it is difficult to use squares. A different approach would be needed.

Comment: The logic of the [Sudoku solver](https://github.com/ipower2/Sudoku-Solver/blob/master/sudokusolver/plotutilities.py) created by @ipower2 may be helpful. Please refer to it.